# Why does modifying the value of an element in an ArrayList change that of the other?

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to get the lastElement of 2D arrayList called point and add that last element back to list as a new element with updated Y value and same X value. So basically what i m doing is getting last element of point 2D array, add it at the end of point 2D array but with change to y value to it. But problem is that when i change y value, it also changes the value of the element from which the information was taken.

```
List<List<Integer>> point = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
    List<Integer> values= new ArrayList<Integer>();
    values.add(1);//x
    values.add(2);//y

    point.add(values);
    point.add(point.get(point.size()-1));
    point.get(0).set(1, 200);
    System.out.println(point);
```

output:[[1, 200], [1, 200]]
Expected output: [[1, 2], [1, 200]]

Comment: Show us the code, show expected and current output...

Comment: Please clarify more. Show some code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Finding the code. sorry

Comment: Please provide some code

Comment: done guys. Sorry for not providing earlier

Comment: What do you mean by saying `the end of 2D ArrayList`?

Comment: I made post more clean and clear now.. Sorry

Comment: Is it a 2D ArrayList or a nested ArrayList?

Comment: Why do you think it *copies* the list you're passing to `add`? Where does it suggests that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### 1

```
point.add(point.get(point.size()-1));
```

doesn't do what you think. It adds a `reference` to the second last element in the arraylist to the last. So when you try to display the value from the last element, it actually fetches the data from the second last `values` in `point` and displays that. To modify the data separately, replace the line I pointed out with this:

```
point.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(values));
```

So you should separately add two copies of `values` in the end of `point`.

### 2

```
point.get(0).set(1, 200); //0 denotes first element. not last
```

will give you this output:

```
[[1, 200], [1, 2]]
```

this should be replaced with

```
point.get(point.size() - 1).set(1, 200); //last element
```

Correcting these two errors will give you the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this

```
    List<List<Integer>> point = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
    List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    values.add(1);// x
    values.add(2);// y

    point.add(values);
    List<Integer> secondList = new ArrayList<Integer>(point.get(point
            .size() - 1));
    secondList.set(1, 200);
    point.add(secondList);
    System.out.println(point);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    List<List<Integer>> point = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
    List<Integer> values= new ArrayList<Integer>();
    values.add(1);//x
    values.add(2);//y

    point.add(values);

    List<Integer> values2= new ArrayList<Integer>();
    values2.add(point.get(point.size()-1).get(0));
    values2.add(point.get(point.size()-1).get(1));

    point.add(values2);
    point.get(1).set(1, 200);
    System.out.println(point);
```

This will work just fine.
The problem occured since the new element added to point had the same reference as that of initial element. So the changes done will be applied to both elements.

Answer (score -1):

When you add the second entry to point with

```
point.add(point.get(point.size()-1));
```

you actually add the reference to the first array. Therefore it is natural that they will be the same, and also change accordingly.

You would need to create a **new** object as a copy for it to be unique, such as

```
point.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(point.get(point.size()-1)));
```